Create a Product table with common data types in Python
Here is the problem in my Zybook:

Write the SQL to create a Product table with the following columns:

ID - Integer
Name - Variable-length string with maximum 40 characters
ProductType - Variable-length string with maximum 3 characters
OriginDate - Year, month, and day
Weight - Decimal number with six significant digits and one digit after the decimal point

Place your CREATE TABLE statement before the INSERT and SELECT statements. Run your solution and verify the result table contains the three inserted rows.

So far, this is the program that I have:
-- Write your CREATE TABLE statement here:
CREATE TABLE Product (
ID             INSERT(int),
Name           VARCHAR(40),
Product Type   VARCHR(3),
OriginDate     Date,
Weight         DECIMAL(6,1)

)

INSERT INTO Product (ID, Name, ProductType, OriginDate, Weight) VALUES 
  (100, 'Tricorder', 'TC', '2020-08-11', 2.4),
  (200, 'Food replicator', 'FOD', '2020-09-21', 54.2),
  (300, 'Cloaking device', 'CD', '2019-02-04', 177.9);

SELECT *
FROM Product;

When I click on "run," this is the error I get:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT(int),
Name           VARCHAR(40),
Product Type   VARCHR(3),
OriginDate   ' at line 2

Could someone please help me?
I have tried to change the attributes, but the scrip can't run.

Where did you learn that syntax for CREATE TABLE? You shouldn't have INSERT() around int. What do you think that does?

It should just be ID INT

The error message points you directly to the problem.

Try this:
CREATE TABLE Product (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(40),
    ProductType VARCHAR(3),
    OriginDate DATE,
    Weight DECIMAL(6,1)
);


INSERT INTO Product (ID, Name, ProductType, OriginDate, Weight) 
VALUES 
    (100, 'Tricorder', 'TC', '2020-08-11', 2.4), 
    (200, 'Food replicator', 'FOD', '2020-09-21', 54.2), 
    (300, 'Cloaking device', 'CD', '2019-02-04', 177.9);


SELECT * FROM Product;

I think problem is missing semicolone and INSERT(int), VARCHR, Product type. Basic typo errors. Hope these helps.

Yes, that worked ! Thank you so much for your help! I can't believe that missing the semicolon was causing the issue.
